# Can Android prevent you from using up the very last bit of your prepaid-service credit?

Tags: 4.3-jelly-bean, mobile-network

Is there a setting that warns you or prevents you from using up the very last bit of your prepaid-service credit? For example, when you are low on credit, but want to prevent yourself from using all of your credit. This way you wouldn't get into a crisis situation unable to call for help. Does such a setting or feature exist in Android?

Comment: By "credit" do you mean calling minutes, data? In newer versions of Android there are controls around data usage, but I haven't seen anything about calling minutes, aside from carrier-specific apps/widgets.  Also, as far as I know you can always dial emergency numbers (e.g. "911" in the US), even if you don't have a SIM card installed.

Comment: @Chahk Yes, I mean the credit you have on your account that can be used for calling, texting or data. Because from the moment I hit 1.60 euro, my android phone prevents me making any paid connections. Free connections still work perfectly and other phones still let me use the remaining credit, so my provider told me to "check my phone settings", so that's why I wondered whether there'd be a setting that would do so. I'm completely lost on what may cause this problem.

Comment: Check under `Settings -> Data usage` to see if "Set mobile data limit" option is enabled.  This setting might have a different name depending on your phone and Android OS version.

Comment: What phone do you have, and what carrier are you on? Vanilla Android doesn't know anything about carrier minutes or credit, but if you got your phone from the carrier they could have added a setting.

Comment: @Chahk mobile data limit is not checked.

Comment: @DanHulme im using a huawei ascend g6 and my carrier is Mobile Vikings Belgium. I bought the phone from another courier though. Phones arent sim-locked here so thats not the issue since I could use it correctly for over a month until I hit that 1,60 euro. Im not using Vanilla Android but Emotion UI 2.0 which came with the phone.